# Convert voltage controlled switch into ngspice

Tags: spice, ngspice

I have a circuit file ADA4691 from Analog Devices and it has a different .model V SWITCH versus SW in ngspice with a VON And VOFF instead of VTH for one switching voltage.

How could I approximate the two voltage conditions around the ngspice version?

The models inside are

```
.MODEL SOPEN  VSWITCH (VON=2.0, VOFF=0.8, RON=1e-01, ROFF=1E+09)
.MODEL SCLOSE VSWITCH (VON=-1.0, VOFF=-1.8, RON=1E-01, ROFF=1E+09)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This link [here](http://www.electronicspoint.com/threads/spice-vswitch.25285/) has some info.
If your trying to translate models

First make sure they are an equivalent model.

- Design a simple test spice file that will test the model with a voltage source.
- Test the model that you want to use in a different spice package so you know what the correct result is
- Test the SW model and 'play around' with it until you get the same result.

It will take some work, but somebody's got to do it.